# How to run main in a Scala object from Maven

Tags: scala, maven

I am trying to use the exec:java goal of maven to run a scala object

The class has already been compiled and we can see from javap that it has a static main :

```
javap sql/hbase/target/scala-2.10/test-classes/org/apache/spark/sql/hbase/HBaseMainTest.class | grep main
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
```

Let us try to run this as follows:

```
mvn  exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.apache.spark.sql.hbase.HBaseMainTest"
```

However the result

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.hbase.HBaseMainTest
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:281)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

**UPDATE**

Gabor provided answer and here is the working solution:

```
mvn  exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.apache.spark.sql.hbase.HBaseMainTest" -Dexec.classpathScope="test"
```

Comment: Does `exec:java` adds the test classes to the classpath? That would be surprising imho.

Comment: @GáborBakos You are probably on the right track.

Comment: in my case I had to add a quotation around  -Dexec parameters like : 

mvn exec:java '-Dexec.mainClass=com.Example.myClass' '-Dexec.classpathScope=test'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting the property [classpathScope](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#classpathScope) to `test`. It seems your main class is among the tests:

```
mvn  exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.apache.spark.sql.hbase.HBaseMainTest" -Dexec.classpathScope="test"
```

Comment: Sorry, I have made a typo, used `:` instead of `.` in the command separating `exec` and `classpathScope`. Could you try the updated?

Comment: works for me but just need to add quotation mark for parameters like :

mvn exec:java '-Dexec.mainClass=com.Example.myClass' '-Dexec.classpathScope=test